# How can I count the time complexity of this recursive function? (BST)

Tags: c, recursion, tree, binary

I've got some troubles counting the time complexity of the function that i wrote for my task.

This function is recursive and it counts how many leaves with value that is greater than 10 in the Binary Search Tree. Here is the function:

```
int count_leaf(node* root)
{
  static int count = 0; 
  int call; 
  if (root == NULL) 
   {
     return 0;
   }
  call = count_leaf(root->left);
  if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL && root->data > 10)
   {
     count++;
   }
  call = count_leaf(root->right); 
  return count;
}
```

What's the most right and proper way to count the time complexity for this function?

Comment: So it is traversing all of the nodes, right? How many nodes are there?

Comment: Umm, does it matter how many nodes in the tree? It's useless information for counting the time complexity as i know, but ok, let's say 33.

Comment: Assume that you know how long it takes to process a particular tree. If you add one more node to that tree, how much longer do you expect it to take?

Comment: Your implementation is broken if you try to call your function more than once.

Comment: In the specific task a had no need to call it more than once. But if yes, i can just define this counter as a global variable and each time initialize it to zero before the function call

Comment: This is not an O n log n operation.

Answer (score 2):

It touches every node of the tree exactly once, so there will be `n` calls, making it `O(n)`.

Comment: Thanks! And there is no way to optimize it right? Cause i litterally have to check each leaf if it has the value greater than 10 or not...

Comment: Actually there is....think about how the nodes in a Binary Search Tree are arranged.  What does it have to do with their values?

Comment: If you'll be doing many checks with various values over time, it might make sense put the computational time into creating a Binary Search Tree (BST) from your binary tree. Once you have a well constructed (somewhat balanced) BST, each call will take ~O(logN) time instead of ~O(N).

Comment: IMHO, that depends on *what* time complexity you are interested in - worst case? Average?

Comment: Another possibility (you are probably not looking for, but just in case ...) would be to cache the leaves you are interested in.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is actually `O(n)` as you need to visit all the nodes. This is better than `O(n*log n)` associated with binary trees. It is also asymptotically optimal.

The child nodes are accessed directly from the parent node rather from the root, and so on for each child, and accessing child nodes this way is a constant time operation. As the traversal finishes, all `n` nodes have been visited.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to experimentally gauge the complexity of an algorithm implementation is to put counter(s) at the start of the function or loop(s) that are used to iterate. For your example something like the following:

```
int test_count = 0;

int count_leaf(node* root)
{
  static int count = 0; 
  int call; 

  ++test_count;

  // ...

}
```

Then print out the value of `test_count` after you run the test.  If you do the experiment with different test sets (make each set twice the size of the previous to make differences obvious) you'll get a good indicaton of whether an algorithm is O(1), O(n), O(n^2), etc.

An alternative is to use a simple timer to measure the duration of test runs.  Compare the time to run an algorithm with several datasets that double in size.  The difference in the amount of time to process each dataset will give you an indication of the algorithms computational complexity.  See Sedgewick's "Algorithms" 4th Edition, Section 1.4 for a couple examples.

Obviously these are not proofs and might not be acceptable for most homework answers - but it can help you make sure you got the *right* homework answer.

Comment: A few questions: is it important that the incrementation will be marked before the variable name as you did?
And how can i implement this function without using static or global counter? I can't see the proper way to solve it in another way :(

Comment: Since the increment evaluation isn't used as part of a larger expression, the detail of which type of increment isn't important. `test_count++`, `test_count += 1`, or `test_count = test_count+1` all would work fine here.  I don't think there would be an easy,  clean way of using the counter without it being a global.  This method is really just for experimentation.